# can-config sample-point setup

Tags: canbus

I need to setup sample-points for CANFD bus. The following help command shows how to setup sample-points for can, but my can configurations is not showing any sample points argument

## ip link set can0 type can help Usage: ip link set DEVICE type can   [ bitrate BITRATE [ sample-point SAMPLE-POINT] ] |   [ tq TQ prop-seg PROP_SEG phase-seg1 PHASE-SEG1    phase-seg2 PHASE-SEG2 [ sjw SJW ] ]   [ dbitrate BITRATE [ dsample-point SAMPLE-POINT] ] |   [ dtq TQ dprop-seg PROP_SEG dphase-seg1 PHASE-SEG1    dphase-seg2 PHASE-SEG2 [ dsjw SJW ] ]   [ tdcv TDCV tdco TDCO tdcf TDCF ]   [ loopback { on | off } ]   [ listen-only { on | off } ]   [ triple-sampling { on | off } ]   [ one-shot { on | off } ]   [ berr-reporting { on | off } ]   [ fd { on | off } ]   [ fd-non-iso { on | off } ]   [ presume-ack { on | off } ]   [ cc-len8-dlc { on | off } ]   [ tdc-mode { auto | manual | off } ]   [ restart-ms TIME-MS ]   [ restart ]   [ termination { 0..65535 } ]   Where: BITRATE  := { NUMBER in bps }      SAMPLE-POINT  := { 0.000..0.999 }      TQ    := { NUMBER in ns }      PROP-SEG  := { NUMBER in tq }      PHASE-SEG1  := { NUMBER in tq }      PHASE-SEG2  := { NUMBER in tq }      SJW    := { NUMBER in tq }      TDCV    := { NUMBER in tc }      TDCO    := { NUMBER in tc }      TDCF    := { NUMBER in tc }      RESTART-MS  := { 0 | NUMBER in ms }

. I am suspecting this is set to 0 by default. Which matches the can.txt resources. This document mentions calculation of bit-timing manipulation is enabled in the kernel (CONFIG_CAN_CALC_BITTIMING). But I am having trouble at which location this (CONFIG_CAN_CALC_BITTIMING) enabling should happen in kernel file.
I would really appreciate help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello L Galib. Please take the time to format the commands and code in your question. Right now it's close to unreadable. Select the commands text and use the `{}` button. But also make sure that lines are laid out correctly and not just smashed together like they are at the moment. Help us to help you

Comment: Read `man ip ip-link`.